# Updating Active Directory users email with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to change a lot of users "email" field on their active directory profile however I can`t seem to find the answer I`m looking for looking at other posts.

I`m quite new to powershell but I've landed this task to be done at work.

The email address format is in the style of "first name" and "lastname" seperated by a "." with the domain appended on the end naturally.

An example would be John.Doe@domain.com

How would I go about this with powershell with users in 6 different OUs but all under the same root OU?

Kind regards

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Is the format you describe the desired format or ??

Comment: The format listed is correct yes, so first name with their last name separated by a "." with the domain on the end.  So it's firstname.lastname@domain.com. All the email fields are blank, I haven't got anything yet as I've been trying to look for something that matches what I need but I'm no good at powershell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have the data.  If you already have the emails in say a csv with a column titled "OldEmail" and "NewEmail" you could do something like:

```
$csv = import-csv \\path\to\csv
foreach($user in $csv) {
get-aduser -filter {mail -eq $user.OldEmail} | Set-ADUser -EmailAddress $user.NewEmail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below, but as always when changing stuff in Active Directory,
**try it out on a bunch of testusers first**

```
# enter the root OU DistinguishedName where the sub OU's are here
$rootOU = "OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"

# Get a list of user objects that do not have an email address in 'firstname.lastname@yourdomain.com' format.
# you only have to ask for property EmailAddress (LDAP name is 'mail'), because these properties are returned by default:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $rootOU -SearchScope Subtree -Properties EmailAddress |
Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -ne ('{0}.{1}@yourdomain.com' -f $_.GivenName, $_.Surname) } |
ForEach-Object {
    $mail = '{0}.{1}@yourdomain.com' -f $_.GivenName, $_.Surname
    Write-Host "Setting up email address $mail for user $($_.SamAccountName)"
    $_ | Set-ADUser -EmailAddress $mail
}
```